# Tensorflow keras initializing Sequential() model raises ValueError: 'Checkpoint'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sequential

I'm using Keras and Tensorflow and made some neural networks. first I build them on my CPU and it was working fine. Now I installed everything to use my GPU, and suddenly I get this error:

"_assert_trackable raise ValueError(
ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting root to be a trackable object (an object derived from `Trackable`), got <weakref at 0x000001B070BBE860; to 'Sequential' at 0x000001B05DA1E100>. If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue."

The error raises with the simple line of code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
```

I'm not using Checkpoint and I'm not trying to save the network.
I have multiple sequential networks I'd like to train with a GPU and I don't understand the problem.

I'm just trying to create a Sequential model and I don't even try to save it or anything. it works with my CPU, but not my GPU.

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you include the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Try `from tensorflow.keras import Sequential`.